# Are there any style rules or conventions for uppercase F, R or B in string literals (formatted, raw, bytes)

Tags: python

The language specification allows an uppercase F"string" and also uppercase R"raw" or B"bytes", but today I saw it for the first time used in an answer.

Not sure why we have both upper and lower case, because *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"*.

Are there any rules when to prefer the upper case over the usual f"string", r"raw" or b"bytes"?

Comment: PEP 498 clearly states that either f or F can be used. They are precisely equivalent. I guess it's a case of personal preference although the vast majority of code seems to use the lowercase variant

Comment: Despite the stated rules I strongly agree in the fact, that only one should be the correct syntax or way of writing it in order to remove confusion. That's my opinion.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49358590/12671057)

Answer (score 0):

Both are perfectly equivalent and will produce the exact same results. However, I'd always use the lowercase version simply because that seems to be the convention which means that you might be able to save other people a trip to Google and depending on what program you use for linting or syntax highlighting it might throw a fit if you use the uppercase prefixes.